# Gram-Schmidt process and degenerate subspace of the solutions to the Schrodinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

So I know that in QM each linear combination of a degenerate set of wavefunctions is also a solution to the Schrodinger's equation (SE). The degenerate wavefunctions must be orthogonal to the non-degenerate wavefunctions of SE (because they have different eigenvalues), but they don't need to be orthogonal with each other. However, it is possible to trasnform the set of the degenerate functions in order to obtain an orthogonal set of wavefunction using the Gram-Schmidt process. Now, what I don't understand is how do we know that this elements of this new set still solves the SE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the **linearity** of the time-independent Schrödinger equation in that sub-space, *i.e.* if $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are solutions with the same energy $E$, then

$$H\left(\psi_1+\psi_2\right)=H\psi_1+H\psi_2=E\psi_1+E\psi_2=E\left(\psi_1+\psi_2\right)$$

so $\psi_1+\psi_2$ is also a solution with energy $E$.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt process generates a new set of vectors (a linear combination of the former) that span the same space but are also orthogonal.

Comment: Note that $\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}$ is just a number. Try it yourself with two vectors.